# Update Azure Devops pipelines service connection

Tags: azure, azure-devops

A github service connection was deleted in error on Azure Devops. Is it possible to update the pipeline to use a new service connection?

Comment: Yes, It can be edited if you have necessary [permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57266674/1176573).

Comment: I do have permission but I cannot find the service account configured in the yaml definition

Comment: Yes, you can either change the pipeline to use the new service connection, or create the new service connection to reflect the old name and by doing that you will not have to change the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today and took the time to dig deeper into ADO. The feature is very well hidden...
First you have to select/open the Pipeline, then "Edit" (on top right corner), then "..." (also on top right corner) and there "Triggers". Then open the "YAML" tab in the new window.

- to change the source of the pipeline (name & path) select "Pipeline" below
- to change the service connection to the source repo, selecte "Get sources"  and then you can see and change the available / authorized Connections on the right side..

In total a lot of options to manage the pipeline, but not very obviously placed.

Answer (score 0):

Access the pipeline that uses github, and edit a message will appear for you to correct the connection.

Comment: when I try to edit I get this error 
Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'templatePath')